# Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ cluster configuration properties

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties and it is not clear to me how these two properties work together:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=address1
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=address1,address2
```

I'm working with a cluster of several hosts, can I only specify the `addresses` property? I don't want the `host` property to be searching for `localhost` (default value if you do not specify it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't work "together". Use `host` (or `addresses`) for a single server, `addresses` for a cluster.

`host` is ignored if `addresses` is provided.

That should be clarified that in the Boot documentation.

The [connection factory Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/AbstractConnectionFactory.html#setAddresses-java.lang.String-) make it clear...

```
/**
 * Set addresses for clustering.
 * This property overrides the host+port properties if not empty.
 * @param addresses list of addresses with form "host[:port],..."
 */
public void setAddresses(String addresses) {
```

Comment: It's already fixed in the upcoming Boot 2.3 release: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/722d37468b2e94a1fbfd24fc82324e63799a32cf#diff-fe82cdd5645cbc56310d1901d5c60103